# How to fix cookie rejection because of invalid domain?

Tags: cookies, tracking, marketo

We are experiencing some strange behaviur on a landing page - tracking cookies that were set when user gave consent, are later being rejected when user refreshes the page (!?).

**Steps:**

(in Firefox / Firefox Dev Edition - because the warning is not visible in e.g. Chrome)

1. => [url-removed]
2. => "Accept all". At this stage you can see a "_mkto_trk" (Marketo Tracking) cookie via dev tools.
3. => Go to the console tab in web dev tools and refresh the page.

Now you should be able to see a warning in the console log saying:

**Cookie “_mkto_trk” has been rejected for invalid domain.**

You can also see that the previous set _mkto_trk cookie is no longer set.

**Expected Results**

The expected result is for the cookie to persist after the page refreshes.

**Regarding the warning**

In the MDN Web Docs it says that:

> The invalid cookie domain error is a WebDriver error that occurs when
> an illegal attempt was made to set a cookie under a different domain
> than that of the current document.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/InvalidCookieDomain

The current document, the landing page in other words is on a subdomain: blog.example.com

But the cookie is set at ".example.com" which should make it valid for subdomains as well.

**What have I tried?**

- Well I have been looking for answers in order to better understand where the issue is coming from, without any success.

Any help would be much appreciated, and thanks in advance!

P.S. This is my first post, so any hints/tips as to how to make this post better, would also be welcome.

---

**Update**

The problem was because of our cookie-script vendor and their trigger for google tag manager - the 'CookieScriptAcceptAll' trigger was not firing.

The solution was to:

1. scan the page for cookies (via cookie-script.com dashboard) which will populate the cookies categories array with cookie categories
2. and use the 'CookieScriptCategory-targeting' trigger instead (changes made via google tag manager dashboard).

Note the solution from above is for cases where you use google tag manager to add tags to your site.

Link to cookie-script documentation for info on triggers:
https://support.cookie-script.com/article/20-custom-events

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I have noticed the same behaviour in Firefox when a cookie's domain is set with a leading dot and the browser URL is `https://example.com` rather than `https://www.example.com`. The latter does not trigger the warning.

Comment: Thanks! Now, on Chrome and Safari, there is no warning but the behavior is the same - the marketo tracking cookie (_mkto_trk) gets rejected and deleted when user refreshes the page.